# How to reupload ipa when "Ready for Sale" in appstoreconnect

Tags: react-native, app-store, expo

Has anyone tried upload ipa new version in appstore, when its already publish (Ready for sale) ?
Im using expo and updated from sdk 33 to sdk 37, so OTA will not work in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's called an "App Store Update". You just need to go into iTunes Connect and create a new version of your app, that allows you to send a new iPA file with the SDK 37 just as you did at first with the very initial version of the app. You must provide a description of what's new in the version and also will let you update more information of the app such as Screenshots or description.

Update:

1 - Login with your Apple developer account in iTunes Connect:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com

2 - Go to `My Apps` and your app must appear in "Ready To Sale" status, select it.

3 - IN the right you will find an option that says "+ Version or Platform", click on it and enter the version number, try it to match with the IPA version you generated from expo (Build number and version must be different from original iPA)

[image]
[image]

Once you've created the new version, you will be able to send the new ipa build from Transporter App, fill out all fields and sent this new version for apple to review it.

Comment: so basically I need to upload it from the start ? but the app.json still the same such us the package name? 

then upload the same image in the production ? 

how about the ready for sale app ? is that not going overlap or two apps with the same app name ?

Comment: No, when you go to the detail of your app in iTunes connect you have the option to send an update of an existing app by creating a new version. So users will receive the update in the same app name. No need to overlap or anything

Comment: So i need to connect my apple developer account first in itunes and then go to what settings ?